# Tensorflow - how to duplicate an Estimator

Tags: python, tensorflow

Using tensorflow, I have created an [`Estimator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/estimators) named `my_estimator`

When I train this estimator with `my_estimator.train(...)` the weights inside of my estimator change and I get different results for `my_estimator.predict(...)`.

Is there a way to save my estimator model just before training into another variable named `old_estimator` so that I can make predictions before training?  I want this operation to be fast, so it would be nice if I could keep this in RAM.

I'm thinking something like this pseudocode should work:

```
# Do a prediction with our estimator
prediction = next(my_estimator.predict(foo))

# Copy the estimator - this is the function I'm looking for
old_estimator = my_estimator.copy()

# Train our estimator
my_estimator.train(...)

# Should be true
next(old_estimator.predict(foo)) == prediction

# Should be false
next(old_estimator.predict(foo)) == next(my_estimator.predict(foo))
```

Comment: Is this just for predictions? I usually end up using `Estimator.export_savedmodel` and run inference from the SavedModel. But that does write to disk, and won't be particularly fast if you export each time. Another option is to export to SavedModel and do both training and prediction from that rather than the Estimator. You could import it twice and transfer the weights when necessary.